# What is the difference between maven-archetype-mojo and maven-archetype-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Snippet from the output of running the command `mvn archetype:generate > a.txt`:

```
332: remote -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-mojo (An archetype which contains a sample a sample Maven plugin.)
333: remote -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-plugin (An archetype which contains a sample Maven plugin.)
```

Running the following commands generated near-identical pom files and Java source classes:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app-plugin -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-plugin -DinteractiveMode=false

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app-mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-mojo -DinteractiveMode=false
```

So what is the difference between `maven-archetype-mojo` and `maven-archetype-plugin`? Will either of these generate a sample plugin project? Why do we have both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. Maven Mojo is a minimal Maven Plugin.

> What is a Mojo? A mojo is a Maven plain Old Java Object. Each mojo is an executable goal in Maven, and a plugin is a distribution of one or more related mojos.

I think we does not need both, just some mess in Maven world :)